# looking for workaround of toggleClass

Tags: jquery

i havw this button where i want a certain class to be added or removed based on whether it has that class already or not. i tries toggleClass and it worked fine, but i was wondering if there is a workround for toggleclass, or toggling in general. here is the thing i used:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      if($('#header-bar a.close').hasClass('activated')) {
          $(this).removeClass('activated');
      } else {
          $(this).addClass('activated');
      }
  });
```

but it is not working. html is here:

```
<div id="header-bar">
not
    <a href="#" class="close"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header-bar a.close{ background-color: #333; color: #ccc; width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer; float: left;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5nRG3/

Comment: Why would you want a workaround?

Comment: `this` refers to window. and whats wrong with `toggleClass`? why you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5nRG3/5/ check this out.

Answer (score 1):

You're not correctly using `this`. In your example it references the ready function, hence it won't add or remove the class to the anchor. Update your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = $('#header-bar a.close');
    if(elem.hasClass('activated')) {
        elem.removeClass('activated');
    } else {
        elem.addClass('activated');
    }
});
```

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nRG3/6/).

Comment: +1, but: *"In your example it references the scope of the ready function"* `this` and scope have nothing to do with one another in JavaScript (until ES6 gives us lexical `this` on "arrow" functions).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed, I always use the term scope though, what would be a better one? As far as I understand the term lexical scoping already exists in ES5?

Comment: @ Anzeo: The *term* exists, it just doesn't relate to `this`. ES6 adds "arrow" functions, whose `this` value is set lexically, not by how the functions are called. Re a term: As far as I'm aware, there is no good one-word term for "the value of `this`". For a while (years back) the PrototypeJS guys were pushing "context," but that's **really** confusing because context already has a specific (different) meaning, and so it didn't catch on. "Scope" is a particularly unfortunate (but not uncommon) term to use for this, because it too has a specific meaning, and is completely unrelated to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

> i tries toggleClass and it worked fine, but i was wondering if there is a workround for toggleclass, or toggling in general. here is the thing i used

Yes, you *can* do it manually. The reason it isn't working for you is that you're applying the change to the wrong object. `this` is not the link/button in that code. Change `this` to be the same object (in this example, I store the result of the lookup in a variable to avoid repeating it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $('#header-bar a.close');
    if(link.hasClass('activated')){
        link.removeClass('activated');
    }
    else{
        link.addClass('activated');
    }
});
```

But this is exactly what `toggleClass` is *for*, avoiding that work.

Note that your code, as presented, only runs when the page is first loaded, and since your HTML doesn't have the class, it always ends up getting added. If your goal is to flip back and forth in response to an event of some kind, you have to attach a handler for the event. For example, this does it when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-bar a.close').on("click", function() {
        // Inside this click handler, `this` is the DOM element for the link
        var link = $(this); // Get a jQuery wrapper
        if(link.hasClass('activated')){
            link.removeClass('activated');
        }
        else {
            link.addClass('activated');
        }
    });
});
```

But again, it can be so much simpler using `toggleClass`, there's not really much reason to "work around" using it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-bar a.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("activated");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-bar a.close').click(function(){     
       $('#header-bar a.close').hasClass('activated')==true?$('#header-bar a.close').removeClass('activated'):$('#header-bar a.close').addClass('activated')
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5nRG3/4/)